# Why isn't MongoDB update working in a Meteor Method?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

I was trying the following Meteor method, but it seems it is not working. Because when I check my DB, I cannot find the updated information.

```
const Employees = new Mongo.Collection("Employees");
Employees.attachSchema(Schemas.Employee, { selector: { type: "fullTime" } });
Employees.attachSchema(Schemas.EmployeeVariant, { selector: { type: "partTime" } });

Meteor.methods({
  "employees/updateTasks": function (employeeId, taskId) {
    this.unblock();

    //the following is printed.
    console.log("employeeId: "+employeeId+" taskId:"+ taskId);
    return Employees.update({_id: employeeId}, 
        {$push: {tasks: taskId}}, 
        {selector: {type: "fullTime"}});
  }
});
```

Is there anything obvious wrong here?

Another question is:

Sometimes I see people using it this way:

```
Employees.update(employeeId,  // not {_id:employeeId}
            {$push: {tasks: taskId}}, 
            {selector: {type: "fullTime"}});
```

It is being used here: "[5.3  Add event handlers for Task buttons](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/update-and-remove)"

Why is this?

My Mongodb's version is 3.2.6

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#selectors explains why we can use a string or object ID as 1st parameter in update operation. Simply put: These selectors match the document with that value in its _id field.

Comment: What's the third argument (`selector...`) that you are passing to `update`? Have you checked that the id is correct?

Comment: Ya, that `selector:` bit isn't doing anything.

Comment: It is updated. I can run this update statement by connecting to the running Meteror Mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that collection hooks (https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) are used here. There is a Employees.before.update method to check what to do before "Employees.update" really happens.